# nginx can't open page containing non-ASCII chacter, gives 404

Tags: nginx, ascii, http-status-code-404, non-ascii-characters

While the file itself exists on the server, nginx gives 404 when trying to access files that contain non-ASCII characters. In this case it is croatian letters: č š ć đ ž

For example: [https://jordanovac.hr/wp-content/uploads/PODLOGA-ZA-MIŠA_4.jpg](https://jordanovac.hr/wp-content/uploads/PODLOGA-ZA-MI%C5%A0A_4.jpg)

The file on the disk is saved exactly as: PODLOGA-ZA-MIŠA_4.jpg

Are there any additional options that should be enabled inside the config file? How to get this to work?

Renaming the files is most certainly not an option, there are more than 10.000 files containing such characters in the filename.

Comment: What file system are you using? Does it use UTF-8?

Comment: @RichardSmith how to check this? for example, files in the filesystem are saved with čšćđž properly, I can see them like that when listing files

Comment: @RichardSmith for example, "cat /etc/default/locale" outputs: LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue in my nginx.

Despite I set in the nginx.conf charset utf-8;, nginx still return error 404 exception for files what has polish characters in filename ex. zdjęcie-32.jpg